# Java - Java.lang.Class Cache on frequently implemented reflection calls

Tags: java

[Is ehcache faster then reflection if I have use heaps of reflection in my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501691/is-ehcache-faster-then-reflection-if-i-have-use-heaps-of-reflection-in-my-projec/24534355#24534355)

As mentioned in this article whether java.lang.Class actually implements a cache for storing frequently called reflections?? If so can anyone please explain the process.??

Comment: Are you seeing a performance hit due to reflection methods ? If yes, then I would recommend using simple `HashMap` like datastructure to cache the outputs. I'm sure your reflection calls won't have GigaBytes of output size for which the EhCache is intended.

Comment: Yes, it implements caching for reflection data. If you are interested in the process, look at the source code for `java.lang.Class`. It defines a boolean `useCaches` which you can use to find the relevant code parts.

Comment: Thanks  @ModusTollens actually it is helpful actually is there any way to know how cache is stored

Comment: It's really best to read the source code to learn about that. Take a look at the `reflectionData` method where reflection data is lazily created and stored (as SoftReference).

Comment: once again thanks @ModusTollens whether based on classRedefinedcount it will be updated if so what is the minimum count to store in cache.